# How to authenticate (ws-security) a scheduled task on WSO2 ESB?

Tags: proxy, wso2, task, ws-security, wso2-esb

I have a proxy on WSO2 Enteprise Service Bus using WS-Security.

I need to do a scheduled task that will call this proxy every day. But I need to post my username and password.

When I create my task, there is no options to authentication! Do I need to create a new Task Implementation?

I know that I can put the credentials inside my payload on "message" field, but I wouldn't like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling directly your proxy from your scheduled task, you could call a sequence which implements the appropriate mediation to manage the authentication